# Plumber API to accept images for API scoring

Tags: r, rest, api, post, plumber

I am trying to write a plumber function to accept images and score on images and return the scored result. So there are two parts I am trying to figure out.

**Part 1:** writing plumber function and this is all I came up with.

```
#* @post /imageAnalysistest
scoreFunction =  function(image){
  ******* need help figuring this part ***********
  image_read(image) %>%
    image_write(paste0(path,"temp.jpg"))
 **************************************************


  # preprocess image
  x = image_load(paste0(path,"temp.jpg"),target_size =  c(img_width, img_height)) %>% 
    array_reshape(c(-1,img_width, img_height, channels))


  # do predictions
  probs = model %>% predict(x, steps = as.integer(test_samples/batch_size), verbose = 1)

  return(probs)
}
```

I tried passing as below and it prints a bunch of characters. I guess its converting image to character?

```
#* @post /imageAnalysistest
scoreFunction =  function(req){
print(req$postBody)
}
```

**Part 2**: curl the data to send a file to score on the image.

```
curl \
  -F "image=@/home/550.jpg" \
    http://192.168.1.1:8085/imageAnalysistest
```

**TLDR:** I am trying to write a plumber function to accept images to score on a image recognition model. I am OK sending a image as raw, so I can convert it to jpg for scoring